# Where to add . swiftdoc and .swiftmodule file using podspec

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add file with extension `.swiftdoc` and `.swiftmodule` through Cocoapods podspecs.

Those files should be added in "import paths" under "swift compiler search paths".

How is it possible?

My current podspect looks like:

```
  s.name         =  'Framework'
  s.version      =  '1.4'
  s.license      =  { :type => '', :file => 'LICENSE.md' }
  s.homepage     =  'http://google.com'
  s.authors      =  { 'orta' => 'saranjith' }

  s.summary      =  ''
  s.description  =  ''

  s.resources    =  'Bundle/Resources.bundle'
  
  s.vendored_libraries = 'Libraries/someName.a'
  s.??  = ModuleMap/someName.swiftmodule
```

Comment: Could you try to elaborate a bit more your purposes? As far as I can see in the podspec, are you trying to create a podspec for a static framework and then include it's module map?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to add static framework and I stuck when adding .swiftmodule file into podspec

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you would like to create a podspec with an static library (by looking at your file extension .a)

Try with something like;

```
s.name         =  'Framework'
  s.version      =  '1.4'
  s.license      =  { :type => '', :file => 'LICENSE.md' }
  s.homepage     =  'http://google.com'
  s.authors      =  { 'orta' => 'saranjith' }

  s.summary      =  ''
  s.description  =  ''

  s.static_framework = true (Potentially needed)
  s.resources    =  'Bundle/Resources.bundle'
  s.vendored_libraries = 'Libraries/someName.a'
  s.source_files = 'Libraries/yourHeaders/*.h'
  s.preserve_paths = 'Libraries/**/*.*' (<-- Potentially you will need to preserve your paths)
```